# Auto scrolling of Excel workbooks saved as web pages

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have downloaded an auto scroll extension in Google Chrome. I have also created an Excel master workbook, which is 80 rows long.

I want to display my master workbook on a big screen. I am saving my master workbook as a webpage, but sadly my auto scroll extension is *not* working for this webpage (for other web pages it is working though).

Comment: it will not work for Excel sheets saved as html.

Comment: Is there anyother way?

Comment: Like displaying 3 different potions of excel sheet separately, by taking a screen shot or so.

Comment: you will need to change the HTML generated by excel to include standard style tags etc. Its too much work honestly for just scrolling. Open it  in IE and use middle button. :)

Comment: Where is middle button?

Comment: Auto scroll what google store says: `It won't work on every page, but it should work on most`. So its really hard to pin point whats going wrong.

Comment: style tags will be very lengthy?

Comment: cann't I copy paste tags of a webpage where my scrolling is working to my excel saved webpage?